# Knex with RDS proxy connection timeout

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, knex.js

I want to use Knex as a query builder with a database connection managed by an RDS proxy. I am using mysql2 as my database driver, which works as expected:

```
const connection = await mysql2.createConnection(myConfig);
const [users] = await connection.query('SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 10'); // Works
```

Based on the [Knex docs](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#connection) and [this comment](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2665#issuecomment-459000887) I believe I should be able to replace this with:

```
const connection = await mysql2.createConnection(myConfig); // Same as above
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql2'
});
const knexUsers = await knex.connection(connection).select('id').from('users').limit(10); // Timeout
```

But this times-out without an error. The code is being run from an AWS Lambda function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your Lambda inside the VPC? Is your Lambda permitted to access the RDS Proxy (Security groups? Same VPC? routes to RDS proxy could be established?)

Comment: Thanks Allan - yes same VPC and the raw query is returning the correct results so the RDS proxy is working.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to my original question, but for anyone else that lands here I decided to use `mysql2` to query my database and use `knex` purely as a query builder, e.g.

```
const knexInstance = knex({
  client: 'mysql2',
});
const query = knexInstance.select('id').from('users').limit(10).toSQL();
const connection = await mysql2.createConnection(config);
const [users] = await connection.query(query.sql, query.bindings);
```

Not particularly elegant but it achieves my main aim, which was to stop writing raw queries.

Additionally this allows me to chain queries, which is a requirement for our project and something I believe `knex` does not support out of the box:

```
const queries = {
  data: knexInstance.select('*').from('users').limit(10).toSQL(),
  count: knexInstance.count('id', { as: 'count' }).from('users').toSQL()
};
const [[data, [{ count }]]] = await connection.query(Object.values(queries).map(query => query.sql).join(";"), Object.values(queries).map(query => query.bindings));
```